# When I am changing branch in visual Studio code my tests are not running

Tags: cypress

I am facing an issue recently. When I am changing branch in visual Studio code my tests are not running

Looking my tests should run

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.